# AVL tree insert method cause segmentation fault

Tags: c++, tree, insert

EDIT: `insert()` seems to be working now, but there's a problem with printing the tree.

```
void AVL::preorder(Node *n) {
    if(n != nullptr) {
        cout << n->value << ", ";
        preorder(n->left);
        preorder(n->right);
    }
}

void AVL::printPreorder() {
    preorder(node);
}
```

My problem is that after I insert first value into the tree, I can't insert more. When I try to insert more than 1 value, program breaks with segmentation fault. I can't find the problem here. Looks like it breaks in `if()` statement but I don't know what is wrong with that. I wrote program using only `struct` at first, and it worked, but I had to modify it to be a whole class with a structure inside it.
EDIT: added main.cpp

```
int main() {

    AVL avl;
    avl.insert(2);
    avl.insert(6); // breaks
    return 0;
}
```

avl.h

```
class AVL {
public:
    struct Node {
        int value;
        int height;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };
    Node* node;

    AVL();
    ~AVL();
    int getHeight(Node *tree);
    Node *newNode(int val);
    Node *rightRotate(Node *y);
    Node *leftRotate(Node *x);
    int getBalance(Node *b);
    Node *insertVal(Node *node, int thisval);
    void preorder(Node *n);
    void printPreorder();
    Node *minValNode(Node *minValNode);
    Node *remove(Node *n, int thisval);
    Node *insert(int val);
};
```

.cpp

```
AVL::AVL() {
        node = nullptr;
    }
AVL::Node* AVL::insertVal(Node *node, int thisval) {
    if(node == nullptr) {
        return newNode(thisval);
    }

    if(thisval < node->value) {
        node->left = insertVal(node, thisval);
    }
    else if(thisval > node->value) {
        node->right = insertVal(node, thisval);
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }

    node->height = max(getHeight(node->left), getHeight(node->right)) + 1;

    int balance = getBalance(node);

    if(balance > 1 && thisval < node->left->value) {
        return rightRotate(node);
    }
    if(balance < -1 && thisval > node->right->value) {
        return leftRotate(node);
    }
    if(balance > 1 && thisval > node->left->value) {
        node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }
    if(balance < -1 && thisval > node->right->value) {
        node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    return node;
}
AVL::Node* AVL::insert(int val) {
    return insertVal(node, val);
}
int AVL::getHeight(Node *tree) {
    if(tree == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return tree->height;
    }
}
AVL::Node* AVL::newNode(int val) {
    node = new Node;
    node->value = val;
    node->height = 1;
    node->left = nullptr;
    node->right = nullptr;
    return node;
}
AVL::Node* AVL::rightRotate(Node *y) {
    Node *x = y->left;
    Node *T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    x->height = max(getHeight(x->left), getHeight(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(getHeight(y->left), getHeight(y->right)) + 1;

    return x;
}
AVL::Node* AVL::leftRotate(Node *x) {
    Node *y = x->right;
    Node *T2 = y->left;

    x->right = T2;
    y->left = x;

    x->height = max(getHeight(x->left), getHeight(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(getHeight(y->left), getHeight(y->right)) + 1;

    return y;
}
int AVL::getBalance(Node *b) {
    if(b == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return getHeight(b->left) - getHeight(b->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried valgrind memcheck it is a game changer tool for likes of these issues

Comment: Do ou have an example where you use the 'insert' method. I do not see where you initialize 'AVL::node' with another value than nullptr

Comment: No I haven't tried it

Comment: @Gojita I use it in main method:  `AVL avl;` `avl.insert(2);`

Comment: @maneel Looks like you've posted all the relevant code except a `main` function that produces the error. Could you add that, takes a bit of the guess work out of fixing your problem.

Comment: Ok ... but I stil do not see where your AVL::node is initialize when you call insert. avl.insert(2) will return to you the new node, but perhaps you have something to do with this newly created node ? Don't you think ? ;-)

Comment: @john I edited my post and added main method :)

Comment: @Gojita When new node is null, I initialize it with the new value and stuff, it's in the first `if()` statement

Comment: You have an infinite recursion in you insertVal method. I propose to you to not use the same name for your root node (AVL::node*) and your parameter. It will then become clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've long forgotten the details of the AVL algorithm but I can explain where your code is crashing. You have an inifinite recursive loop that leads to a stack overflow.

```
AVL::Node* AVL::insertVal(Node *node, int thisval) {
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return newNode(thisval);
    }

    if (thisval < node->value) {
        node->left = insertVal(node, thisval);
    }
    else if (thisval > node->value) {
        node->right = insertVal(node, thisval);
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }
```

In this code and with the main you supplied `thisval > node->value` is true and so `insertval` is called again **with the exact same parameters**. So the whole process repeats, and repeats, and repeats until you get a stack overflow.

I guess you meant this

```
AVL::Node* AVL::insertVal(Node *node, int thisval) {
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return newNode(thisval);
    }

    if (thisval < node->value) {
        node->left = insertVal(node->left, thisval);
    }
    else if (thisval > node->value) {
        node->right = insertVal(node->right, thisval);
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }
```

This bug was discovered in about two minutes using a debugger. At this stage in your development it's probably the most useful thing you can learn to use.

Comment: Oh.. It works now, thanks :) The other problem occurs when I try to print my tree using preorder. It prints only the last added node. I added the code to my post